# Parse xml file with rails REXML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rexml

How can i parse this xml file ?

```
<resultset>
−<row>
<field name="Table Name">table_1</field>
<field name="Quant of Rows">2</field>
<field name="Total Size Mb">0.02</field>
</row>
−<row>
<field name="Table Name">table_2</field>
<field name="Quant of Rows">1</field>
<field name="Total Size Mb">0.02</field>
</row>
</resultset>
```

I am using REXML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    table_data = []
    xml = File.read('file1.xml')
    doc, posts = REXML::Document.new(xml), []
    doc.elements.each('resultset/row') do |table_row|
      table_data << {:table_name => table_row.elements[1].text,
        :record_count => table_row.elements[2].text,
        :size_in_mb => table_row.elements[3].text
      }
    end
```